# Always show first item while filtering radcombobox

Tags: c#, asp.net, telerik

I have telerik radcombobox and it has some items bind to it from database.Always the first item will be **"New Account"** and rest will add next to it.
My code is aspx

```
 <telerik:RadComboBox ID="cmdAccounts" runat="server" 
 AllowCustomText="true" MarkFirstMatch="true" Filter="Contains">
 </telerik:RadComboBox>
```

aspx.cs pageload code is

```
 RadComboBoxItem NewItem = new RadComboBoxItem("New Account","0");
 cmdAccounts.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
 cmdAccounts.DataTextField = "Account_Name";
 cmdAccounts.DataValueField = "Account_Number";
 cmdAccounts.DataBind();
 cmdAccounts.Items.Insert(0, NewItem);
```

my issue here is when i enter text in radcombobox to filter ,filter is working fine but i want **"New Account"** to be visible always first as default and filtered items next to it.
I mean filter should show filtered items along with **"New Account"** displayed at first and should be client side.

Thank You

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you have to handle the RadComboBox1_ItemsRequested() event. Over there you have to fech the filtered data from the db insert your default iem to the the first and assign it to the combo box data source.

Comment: Thank you and i have implemented using header template in radcombobox and every thing is good now .Thank you once again

Comment: @Ramu Sagar - Glad to help you. You can mark it as your answer then. :)